# HttpServletRequest parametersmap is empty intermittently

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have exposed an api that consumes application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I am using HttpServletRequest in Spring based controller and retrieving list of parameters via getParameterMap().

For most of the request it is working fine but intermittently I am getting empty list of parameters even though caller confirmed that request does contain parameter.

```
  @PostMapping(
      value = ''/status,
      consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE},
      produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
  public String status(final HttpServletRequest request) { 

      Map<String, String[]> requestParams = request.getParameterMap();
      String myHeader = request.getHeader(X_CUSTOM_HEADER_1));

      ...

      }
```

Comment: Maybe you could enable logging the raw HTTP requests? Maybe this [filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html) with [setIncludePayload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html#setIncludePayload-boolean-)

Comment: thanks @roby. this will definitely help. since CommonsRequestLoggingFilter works on debug only I need to write custom extension of AbstractRequestLoggingFilter to log at info level

Comment: @roby even in CommonsRequestLoggingFilter, payload is missing/empty in some of requests. looks like payload is getting dropped somewhere between client and my api. client is calling akamai url, which then gets forwarded to aws route53 and then to EC2 instance

Comment: @AkshayGarg i am facing similar issue, did u figureout what was the issue in ur case?